# How to select from the drop down using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

Please see the code below where I need to click on dropdown so that list is displayed

```
<span class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header" style="" unselectable="on" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns="" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-busy="false">
    <span class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default k-state-hover k-state-focused" unselectable="on">
    <span class="k-input" unselectable="on">Is equal to</span>
    <span class="k-select" unselectable="on">
        <span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s" unselectable="on">select</span>
    </span>
</span>
```

[image]

Comment: Didyou try `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[class='k-widget k-dropdown k-header']")).click()` yet?

Comment: Sorry the code doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".k-widget k-dropdown k-header")).click()
```

Comment: Could you please provide the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

I think you again have to try by clicking using `JavascriptExecutor`

```
WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='k-widget k-dropdown k-header' and @role='listbox']"));
JavascriptExecutor executor1 = (JavascriptExecutor) oBrowser;
executor1.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element1);
```

If above Xpath didn't work then try below:-

```
//span[@class='k-widget k-dropdown k-header']
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: hi, actually its continuation to the filter which u had replied. After clicking on filter we will get a pop-up having drop downs containing is equal to, starts with, contains etc 
Do we need to switch from window to pop-up and click on drop down so that list is displayed

Comment: It's depends that it's a browser pop-up or application pop-up .. If direct clicking is not working then definitely you need to switch your control.

Comment: Can you provide me the script by seeing the given code above which is continuation of the filter

Comment: what value do you want to select after dropdown click? .. is click on drop down click working fine?

Comment: Is click on drop down working fine - NO.
that's what I want to do, to click on the drop down first and then select the desired option, the pop-up starts displaying option is equal to in default

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this exact issue the other day. The problem is the Kendo UI `<span>` element you are referencing uses a `<ul>` element to get it's innertext but it's the `<ul>` list that handles the option change/selection. You won't be able to select an option from the pop-up/dropdown you see when clicking the `<span>`, you have to click the `<li>` element that holds the text options referenced by the span.

In your example, somewhere else in the HTML document you'll find a `<ul>` list similar to...

```
<ul unselectable="on" class="k-list k-reset" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" aria-live="off" data-role="staticlist" role="listbox">
    <li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item k-state-selected k-state-focused" data-offset-index="0">is equal to</li>
    <li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="1">another option</li>
</ul>
```

Using Selenium 3, if you wanted to select "another option":

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[text()='another option']")).click();`

You should see your `<span>` innertext change to 'another option' and you can continue on your testing journey.